# Removing *NEARLY* Duplicate Observations - Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am attempting to remove some observations in a pandas DataFrame where the similarities are ALMOST 100% but not quite. See frame below:

[image]

Notice how "John", "Mary", and "Wesley" have nearly identical observations, but have one column being different. The real data set has 15 columns, and 215,000+ observations. In all of the cases I could visually verify, the similarities were likewise: out of 15 columns, the other observation would match up to 14 columns, every time. For the purpose of the project I have decided to remove the repeated observations (and store them into another DataFrame just in case my boss asks to see them).

I have evidently thought of `remove_duplicates(keep='something')`, but that would not work since the observations are not ENTIRELY similar. Has anyone ever encounter such an issue? Any idea on a remedy?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise but I had a couple ideas. I'd consider having some threshold number of identical columns. Like, if you have 15 columns, and your threshold is 12, then if 12-15 cells match, you consider it a duplicate. But if 11 or fewer are matches then you don't consider it a duplicate. Or something like that, maybe you actually want to be ignoring certain columns entirely for duplicate checks. Like in your example, maybe you'd ignore salary. It depends on how you want it designed though. Does any of that seem useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group near-duplicate values in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018512/how-to-group-near-duplicate-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @DavideFiocco. Somewhat similar, but entirely different similarity metric. I would say this is sufficiently different.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that at least one of the columns is the same for all nearly-duplicate entries?

Comment: For example, do you require the name to always be the same? If so, how many different people are you likely to get per name? How many duplicate entries peer person? If both are small enough, this is a simple problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The names will always be the same when the observations are nearly-duplicates. What will vary is the age, salary or city. i.e. the near-duplication is caused due to a difference in age, salary or city. I am thinking of removing the second of near-duplicates. Example: john, 22, 45k, dc would stay but john, 25, 45k, dc would be removed.

Comment: One more question. Is there ever a situation that you need to detect where people with the same name are not duplicates?

Comment: I would first apply column-wise transformation and then remove duplicates. incase, you need original data back, use the deduplicated index on the original dataset. For example, john,22,45k,dc and john,25,45k,dc both become john,20,40k,dc. Now, remove city column and remove duplicates. Finally, use the index to get back original deduplicated data.

Comment: the numpy function `isclose()` will let you set thresholds for how close is close enough

Comment: @PereNoel wondering if there is anything you were expecting but didn't find in my solution below

Comment: if the same name differs by age in different records, do you need a threshold to mark the records as unique. for instance, john aged 22 is likely a different person than john aged 68.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be formulated as a pair-wise Hamming distance calculation between all records, separating out subsequent pairs below some threshold.  Fortunately, numpy/scipy/sklearn already has done the heavy lifting.  I've included two functions that produce identical output - one that is fully vectorized (but consumes O(N^2) memory) and another that consumes O(N) memory but is only vectorized along a single dimension.  At your scale, you almost certainly *don't* want the fully vectorized version - it will likely give an OOM error.  In both cases, the basic algorithm is as follows:

- encode each feature value as an integer value (thanks sklearn!)
- for all row pairs, calculate the Hamming distance (sum of different values)
- if two rows are found at `threshold` or below Hamming distance, discard the latter until no rows remain below that threshold

code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np


def dedupe_fully_vectorized(df, threshold=1):
    """
    fully vectorized memory hog version - best not to use for n > 10k
    """
    # convert field data to integers
    enc = OrdinalEncoder()
    X = enc.fit_transform(df.to_numpy())

    # calc the (unnormalized) hamming distance for all row pairs
    d = pdist(X, metric="hamming") * df.shape[1]
    s = squareform(d)

    # s contains all pairs (j,k) and (k,j); exclude all pairs j < k as "duplicates"
    s[np.triu_indices_from(s)] = -1
    dupe_pair_matrix = (0 <= s) * (s <= threshold)

    df_dupes = df[np.any(dupe_pair_matrix, axis=1)]
    df_deduped = df.drop(df_dupes.index).sort_index()
    return (df_deduped, df_dupes)


def dedupe_partially_vectorized(df, threshold=1):
    """
    - Iterate through each row starting from the last; examine all previous rows for duplicates.  
    - If found, it is appended to a list of duplicate indices.
    """
    # convert field data to integers
    enc = OrdinalEncoder()
    X = enc.fit_transform(df.to_numpy())

    """
    - loop through each row, starting from last
    - for each `row`, calculate hamming distance to all previous rows
    - if any such distance is `threshold` or less, mark `idx` as duplicate
    - loop ends at 2nd row (1st is by definition not a duplicate)
    """
    dupe_idx = []          
    for j in range(len(X) - 1):
        idx = len(X) - j - 1
        row = X[idx]
        prev_rows = X[0:idx]
        dists = np.sum(row != prev_rows, axis=1)
        if min(dists) <= threshold:
            dupe_idx.append(idx)
        dupe_idx = sorted(dupe_idx)
    df_dupes = df.iloc[dupe_idx]
    df_deduped = df.drop(dupe_idx)
    return (df_deduped, df_dupes)
```

Now lets test things out.  Sanity check first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["john", "doe", "m", 23],
        ["john", "dupe", "m", 23],
        ["jane", "doe", "f", 29],
        ["jane", "dole", "f", 28],
        ["jon", "dupe", "m", 23],
        ["tom", "donald", "m", 12],
        ["john", "dupe", "m", 65],
    ],
    columns=["first", "last", "s", "age"],
)


(df_deduped_fv, df_dupes_fv) = dedupe_fully_vectorized(df)
(df_deduped, df_dupes) = dedupe_partially_vectorized(df)

df_deduped_fv == df_deduped # True

# df_deduped
#   first    last  s  age
# 0  john     doe  m   23
# 2  jane     doe  f   29
# 3  jane    dole  f   28
# 5   tom  donald  m   12

# df_dupes
#   first  last  s  age
# 1  john  dupe  m   23
# 4   jon  dupe  m   23
# 6  john  dupe  m   65
```

I've tested this on dataframes up to ~40k rows (as below) and it seems to work (the two methods give identical results), but may take several seconds.  I've haven't tried it at your scale, but it may be slow:

```
arr = np.array("abcdefgh")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(arr, (40000, 15))
# (df_deduped, df_dupes) = dedupe_partially_vectorized(df)
```

If you can avoid doing *all* pairwise comparisons, such as grouping by name, that will improve performance significantly.

**fun aside/issues with approach**

You may notice you can get interesting "Hamming chains" (I don't know if this is a term) where very different records are connected by a chain of one-edit difference records:

```
df_bad_news = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["john", "doe", "m", 88],
        ["jon", "doe", "m", 88],
        ["jan", "doe", "m", 88],
        ["jane", "doe", "m", 88],
        ["jane", "doe", "m", 12],
    ],
    columns=["first", "last", "s", "age"],
)


(df_deduped, df_dupes) = dedupe(df)

# df_deduped
#   first last  s  age
# 0  john  doe  m   88

# df_dupes
#   first last  s  age
# 1   jon  doe  m   88
# 2   jan  doe  m   88
# 3  jane  doe  m   88
# 4  jane  doe  m   12
```

Performance will be greatly improved if there is a field you can groupby on (it was mentioned in the comments that `name` is expected to be identical).  Here the pairwise calculation is n^2 in memory.  It is possible to trade some time efficiency for memory efficiency as needed.

Comment: nice! very elegant solution. perhaps you could group by name & dedup within each group.

Answer (score 4):

What about a simple loop over subset of columns :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ['John', 45, 85000, 'DC'],
            ['Netcha', 25, 48000, 'NYC'],
            ['Mary', 45, 85000, 'DC'],
            ['Wesley', 36, 72500, 'LA'],
            ['Porter', 22, 98750, 'Seattle'],
            ['John', 45, 105500, 'DC'],
            ['Mary', 28, 85000, 'DC'],
            ['Wesley', 36, 72500, 'Boston'],
        ], 
        columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Salary', 'City'])

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols.remove('Name')

for col in cols:
    observed_cols = df.drop(col, axis=1).columns.tolist()
    df.drop_duplicates(observed_cols, keep='first', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Returns :

```
     Name  Age  Salary     City
0    John   45   85000       DC
1  Netcha   25   48000      NYC
2    Mary   45   85000       DC
3  Wesley   36   72500       LA
4  Porter   22   98750  Seattle
```

Answer (score 2):

The python library [pandas-dedupe](https://github.com/Lyonk71/pandas-dedupe) can do what you want.

Have a look at this answer:
[What is the most efficient way to dedupe a Pandas dataframe that has typos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053981/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-dedupe-a-pandas-dataframe-that-has-typos/62863515#62863515)